# JSON TO CSV Conversion Notice: Array to string conversion in

Tags: php, json, csv

I am Trying to Convert JSON Data to CSV but it says that **"Notice: Array to string conversion in D:\xampp\htdocs\api.pharmarack.com\Model\ConverterModel.php on line 427"**

**MyJSON:**

```
[
    {
        "FirmId": "1",
        "OrderNo": "RP89",
        "PartyCode": "7026",
        "Status":"Processed",
        "InvoiceNo":"INV123",
        "InvoiceDate": "2017-12-02",
        "OrderDate": "2017-12-02 11:43:38.321813",
        "OrderDetails": [
            {
                "Item": "ZAART 50 MGTAB",
                "ItemDetailId": "22047",
                "OrderedQty": "17",
                "ProcessedQty":"17",
                "ProcessedPTR":"24.5",
                "ProcessedMRP":"30.5"
            },
            {
                "Item": "RBTONE CAPS",
                "ItemDetailId": "6091",
                "OrderedQty": "10",
                "ProcessedQty":"0",
                "ProcessedPTR":"0",
                "ProcessedMRP":"0"
            },
            {
                "Item": "EBASIL 20MG",
                "ItemDetailId": "80253",
                "OrderedQty": "20",
                "ProcessedQty":"15",
                "ProcessedPTR":"45.0",
                "ProcessedMRP":"50.0"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "FirmId": "1",
        "OrderNo": "RP88",
        "PartyCode": "7025",
        "Status":"Processed",
        "InvoiceNo":"INV123",
        "InvoiceDate": "2017-12-02",
        "OrderDate": "2017-12-02 11:31:13.307100",
        "OrderDetails": [
            {
                "Item": "BG PROT L",
                "ItemDetailId": "83570",
                "OrderedQty": "20",
                "ProcessedQty":"15",
                "ProcessedPTR":"45.0",
                "ProcessedMRP":"50.0"
            },
            {
                "Item": "E ZINT LIQ",
                "ItemDetailId": "88417",
                "OrderedQty": "20",
                "ProcessedQty":"15",
                "ProcessedPTR":"45.0",
                "ProcessedMRP":"50.0"
            },
            {
                "Item": "A TO Z DROP",
                "ItemDetailId": "98165",
                "OrderedQty": "20",
                "ProcessedQty":"15",
                "ProcessedPTR":"45.0",
                "ProcessedMRP":"50.0"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**PHP CODE:**

```
$fp = fopen($cfilename, 'w');
$data = json_decode($json, true);
$firstLineKeys = false;
foreach ($data as $line) {
    if (empty($firstLineKeys)) {
        $firstLineKeys = array_keys($line);
        fputcsv($fp, $firstLineKeys);
        $firstLineKeys = array_flip($firstLineKeys);
    }
    $line_array = array($line['FirmId'], $line['OrderNo'], $line['PartyCode'], $line['Status'], $line['InvoiceNo'], $line['InvoiceDate'], $line['OrderDate']);
    foreach ($line['OrderDetails'] as $valueItem) {
        $item_array = array($value['Item'], $value['ItemDetailId'], $value['OrderedQty'], $value['ProcessedQty'], $value['ProcessedPTR'], $value['ProcessedMRP']);
        array_push($line_array, $item_array);
    }
    fputcsv($fp, $line_array);
}

fclose($fp);
```

**Expected Output:**
[image]

Comment: because you are trying to put order details array in csv, you can't put the array in csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help you:

```
<?php

$fp = fopen("demo.csv", 'w');
$data = json_decode($json, true);
$firstLineKeys = false;
foreach ($data as $line) {
    if (empty($firstLineKeys)) {
        $firstLineKeys = array_keys($line);
        $firstLineKeys = array_merge($firstLineKeys, array_keys($line['OrderDetails'][0]));
        unset($firstLineKeys['OrderDetails']);
        fputcsv($fp, $firstLineKeys);
        $firstLineKeys = array_flip($firstLineKeys);
    }
    $line_array = array($line['FirmId'], $line['OrderNo'], $line['PartyCode'], $line['Status'], $line['InvoiceNo'], $line['InvoiceDate'], $line['OrderDate']);
    foreach ($line['OrderDetails'] as $value) {
        $array = $line_array;
        array_push($array, $value['Item'], $value['ItemDetailId'], $value['OrderedQty'], $value['ProcessedQty'], $value['ProcessedPTR'], $value['ProcessedMRP']);
        fputcsv($fp, $array);
    }
}

fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be in this, and then trying to put $line_array into csv...

```
foreach ($line['OrderDetails'] as $value) {
    array_push($line_array, $value);
}
```

From JSON structure, the $value in this loop is an array, because `OrderDetails` is array of objects. So value will be like:

```
            {
                "Item": "ZAART 50 MGTAB",
                "ItemDetailId": "22047",
                "OrderedQty": "17",
                "ProcessedQty":"17",
                "ProcessedPTR":"24.5",
                "ProcessedMRP":"30.5"
            }
```

After that you are putting multidimensional array into fputcsv:

`fputcsv($fp, $line_array);`

EDIT:

Change it for example to this:

```
foreach ($line['OrderDetails'] as $value) {
    $line_array = array_merge($line_array, array_values($value));
}
```

Comment: You are still pushing an array into `$line_array`. So your $line_array contains something like `$line_array[0] = array(...)` ... and it can't! `fputcsv()` excepts only array of strings... not array of arrays. You are probably looking for `array_merge()` instead of `array_push()`. Edited answer to show possible solution.